# Discord Python Rewreite - Channel Searcher

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, i'm trying to make a YouTube channel search, I've made a simple code, but it didn't work, It always sends `https://www.youtube.com/channel/v=XIDzSr3oX1w%22,%22webPageT`, (Not a valid link),
The code is

```
@client.command()
async def channel(ctx, *, search):

    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'search_query': search
        })
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'https://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string
        )
    search_results = re.findall(r'/watch\?v=(.{24})', htm_content.read().decode())
    await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + search_results[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse the search results in youtube. Youtube is a dynamically generated website. If you want to actually parse youtube you will probably need to use youtube API or using [python selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).